# Silverlight XML add node at special position (with LINQ)

Tags: xml, silverlight, linq-to-xml

I do have a XML which looks like this

```
<root>
    <name value="test">
        <contact>
            <id>1</id>
            <Name>myname mylastname</Name>
            <phone>
                <number1_1>123456789</number1_1>
                <number2_1>987654321</number2_1>
            </phone>
        </contact>
        <contact>
            <id>2</id>
            <Name>myname mylastname</Name>
            <phone>
                <number1_2>123456789</number1_2>
                <number2_2>987654321</number2_2>
            </phone>
        </contact>
    </name>
    <name value="test1">
        <contact>
            <id>1</id>
            <Name>myname mylastname</Name>
            <phone>
                <number1_1>123456789</number1_1>
                <number2_1>987654321</number2_1>
            </phone>
        </contact>
    </name>
</root>
```

with this code I can add a new node, but it will be always added under the firstname value test. How can I add it under name value test1 ?

```
xmldoc.Element("root").Element("Name").Add( 
    new XElement("contact",
            new XElement("id", "2"),
            new XElement("Name", "notset"),
            new XElement("phone",
                new XElement("number1_1", "notset"),
                new XElement("number2_1", "notset")

            )
        )
    );
```

Can someone give me hint or a line of code how I can do this!

Regards Martin

Answer (score 0):

`Element("name")` returns first element that matches the name. That's why you to query for your `<name>` element.

```
.Elements("Name").First(x => (string)x.Attribute("value") == "test1")
```

It should do the trick. Whole code would look like that:

```
xmldoc.Element("root")
      .Elements("Name").First(x => (string)x.Attribute("value") == "test1").Add( 
    new XElement("contact",
            new XElement("id", "2"),
            new XElement("Name", "notset"),
            new XElement("phone",
                new XElement("number1_1", "notset"),
                new XElement("number2_1", "notset")

            )
        )
    );
```